# Copy files from one folder to another based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table set up on Excel with a list of file paths in column C, and a list of leagues in column G.

What I would like to do is enter a league name into cell H1, and copy all files into a newly created subfolder (if it doesn't already exist) for all the files that match the selected league.

eg in the below if I had "Essex Olympian Football League Premier Division" in H1, the files for Canning Town, Stortford Swifts, Catholic United, Harold Wood Athletic, Kelvedon Hatch and Leigh Ramblers would copy to a new folder (if it doesn't already exist) located at path & H1 value

[image]

I have the below code thanks to mits, but it picks up an error if the folder exists with the line `MkDir sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1")` - error `run-time error '58': File already exists`

```
    Sub Copy_Files()
Dim rng As Range
Dim firstFound As Long 'we need to hold the row of the first league occurence
Dim lastRow As Long 'the last row in G column
Dim sPath As String 'the folder where you need the subfolder created
Dim sFile As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fso As Object
'Get a reference of the worksheet. You don't specify which worksheet you are into. I assume this is the first one.
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Clubs")
'This is an easy way to get the last row of data in your worksheet.
    lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + ws.UsedRange.Row - 1
'Specify the folder you need the subfolder to be created into.
    sPath = "W:\Gegenpress Graphics\-- Crests Master\Clubs\Leagues"
'Search if the inserted league exists in column G.
    Set rng = ws.Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Find(ws.Range("H1"), , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext)
    firstFound = rng.Row
'If the league exists, check if the subfolder exists. If not, create it.
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If Dir(sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1")) = "" Then _
            MkDir sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1")
    'Create the fso object to make the copies.
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
        Do
        'Isolate the file name from the old path.
            sFile = ws.Range("C" & rng.Row)
            sFile = Right(sFile, Len(sFile) - InStrRev(sFile, "\"))
        'Make the copy. True: overwrites existing file with the same name if any.
            fso.CopyFile Source:=ws.Range("C" & rng.Row), Destination:=sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1") & "\" & sFile, OverWriteFiles:=False
        'Find next league occurence.
            Set rng = ws.Range("G1:G" & lastRow).FindNext(rng)
        Loop Until rng.Row = firstFound 'without this, the find loop never ends
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Which is column C, which cell is H1 in the table in the image?

Answer (score 1):

Put this Sub in a module. Make modifications for the folder and maybe the right worksheet (see the code notes).
This will create subfolder with the league's name.

```
Sub Copy_Files()
Dim rng As Range
Dim firstFound As Long 'we need to hold the row of the first league occurence
Dim lastRow As Long 'the last row in G column
Dim sPath As String 'the folder where you need the subfolder created
Dim sFile As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fso As Object
'Get a reference of the worksheet. You don't specify which worksheet you are into. I assume this is the first one.
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
'This is an easy way to get the last row of data in your worksheet.
    lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + ws.UsedRange.Row - 1
'Specify the folder you need the subfolder to be created into.
    sPath = "C:\Users\name_of_user\Desktop"
'Search if the inserted league exists in column G.
    Set rng = ws.Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Find(ws.Range("H1"), , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext)
    firstFound = rng.Row
'If the league exists, check if the subfolder exists. If not, create it.
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If Dir(sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1")) = "" Then _
            MkDir sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1")
    'Create the fso object to make the copies.
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
        Do
        'Isolate the file name from the old path.
            sFile = ws.Range("C" & rng.Row)
            sFile = Right(sFile, Len(sFile) - InStrRev(sFile, "\"))
        'Make the copy. True: overwrites existing file with the same name if any.
            fso.copyFile Source:=ws.Range("C" & rng.Row), Destination:=sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1") & "\" & sFile, OverWriteFiles:=True
        'Find next league occurence.
            Set rng = ws.Range("G1:G" & lastRow).FindNext(rng)
        Loop Until rng.Row = firstFound 'without this, the find loop never ends
    End If
End Sub
```

This is not tested, but should work.
You can run this everytime you want.

EDIT: some modifications where made, based on comments

Comment: Just some tips (options): In the event, I would prefer `Dim tCell As Range: Set tCell = Me.Range("H1"): If Not Intersect(tCell, Target) Is Nothing Then Copy_Files tCell` which will make it work even when values are copied to e.g. `G1:I1`. In the Sub, you can reference the worksheet using the range: `Set ws = rngH1.Worksheet` (assuming all is happening in the same worksheet). (Automatically) Setting the objects to `Nothing` at the end of the sub is not necessary (frowned upon) in VBA. Keep up the good work.

Comment: I don't want it to run whenever the value in H1 changes, I'd like to just run as and when it's needed based on the H1 value. I'll update my main post with the code I have based on your notes, but I haven't added the private sub part as I don't want it to run automatically.

Comment: @ffc2004 I've made some modifications. Now you can run the procedure every time you need.

Comment: This works great, but if the folder exists I get "run-time error '75': Path/File access error."

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: MkDir sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1")

Comment: This error is usually raised when a path is invalid. Type this `Debug.Print sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1")` before the line that raises the error, run the code again, check the immediate window to see what is the output, and post it here to check it.

Comment: run-time error '58': File already exists